# Create own TextBox class with specific properties in c#

Tags: c#, inheritance, autocomplete, textbox

I am quite new in C# programming. I would need your help in a question about creating own TextBox class (inheriting from the original one) in C#.

How could I create/inherit my own class from the generic TextBox class? My goal would be, that once I create 1 object from my class, the following attributes should be set automatically to all of the instances:

- AutocompleteMode
- AutocompleteSource
- AutocompleteCustomSource

I would avoid to reuse my coding part every time, once I want to use the same text box, but in different forms and/or Tabs.

Thanks in advance,

Matyas

Comment: Assuming this is the Windows Forms text box, you might start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/developing-custom-windows-forms-controls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public MyTextBox()
    {
        //  Change the background color
        this.BackColor = Color.BurlyWood;
        this.Font = new Font("Verdana", 16);
    }
}
```

Build your project.

After that, look in your toolbox:

[image]

I didn't help you answer the auto complete, I have to make dinner now, but I wanted to give you the head start.

Search for auto complete tutorials, and it shouldn't be that hard for you to put a list box below your textbox. For this you want to create a custom User Control, and handle the keydown event of the textbox to filter your list.

Edit: 
You also don't have to inherit from TextBox if you don't need to. What you can also do is combine two controls, like I do here with my LabelTextBoxControl, LabelComboBoxControl, LabelCheckBoxControl, etc. I didn't want to have to always drag two controls on to a form, so I combined a Label and other base controls.

If you want to see a sample open source project that has these type of user controls, (for Windows Forms) it is located here:
https://github.com/DataJuggler/DataJuggler.Win.Controls

P.S. > Always ignore the down voters on this site. This is how I learned to create user controls. Create what you want.